# Svelte export function from component

Tags: javascript, svelte

I wanted to create a component that exposes a function in the parent.
While the Svelte docs point to context="module", that script gets called only once, which would break functionality if I have several instances of the same component.

I found several examples on the internet and they all point to a very handy workaround, defining the export in the component and calling it with dot notation:

```
// Child.svelte

<script>
        let element
        export function changeColor() {
        console.log(element)
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
}
</script>

<button bind:this={element}>A button</button>
```

I created a very simple use case, which works when I bind the component to a variable and call it with child.function, but what if I want to call the function from a click on the component itself?

```
// App.svelte
<script>
    import Child from "./Child.svelte"
    let child
    
</script>
 
<button on:click={() => child.changeColor()}>Click</button>        // This works
<Child bind:this={child} on:click={() => child.changeColor()} />   // This doesn't work
```

I understand the logic behind the first option, however I don't understand why the second option doesn't work!
Should it be the same? I `bind`ed the component to a variable, and I am calling it with the same syntax. How can i make it work, without using a second element that calls the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<Child bind:this={child} on:click={() => child.changeColor()} />
```

doesn't work because `on:click` is not defined, you can easily see this when changing it to `on:click={() => console.log('test')}`

The reason it doesn't work is because in Svelte events do not 'bubble' out of components, if you want to do that you have to explicitly indicate this in *Child.svelte*

```html
<button bind:this={element} on:click>A button</button>
```

Comment: That was excellent,thank you so much!! That fixed my problem, now however I have another question: when I create several instances of the same component, only the last one gets `bind`ed to the element, meaning that the function changeColor now only changes the last button. How could I make the instance bind uniquely to its element?

Comment: you can also bind to an array using the index: `bind:this={elements[i]` but then you have to make sure the indices stay in sync, if you have something that can be used as a unique key you can bind to an object `bind:this={elements[key]` just be aware that in both case destorying the bound element will set the chosen index/key to `null`

Comment: Indeed!! I've playing with it, and have just found a solution. I made a REPL if anyone else wants to have a look at it:
https://svelte.dev/repl/668ba512227a4162ad573044aafb6042?version=3.32.3